# Use Option (Recompile) in an Inline Table Valued Function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Can `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` be used in an Inline Table Valued Function?

I try to use it but it gives me error. If it cannot be used what other way is advisable to recompile a Inline Table Valued Function?

My code will be like

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_abcwork]
(
  @Date date
  , @id VARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN
  SELECT a.name
    , a.age
    , a.title
    , b.work
  from tbl_abc a
  left outer join tbl_emp on a.id=b.id
```

Answer (score 11):

Inline Table Valued Functions are expanded out into the calling query so nothing is ever actually called. Put the `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` on the query that is using the function.